# Component does not route to page of another component

Tags: typescript, angular

Good day. My problem is button with routelink in RegistrationComponent does not route to page of LogInComponent and I can't understand why. Angular does not through any errors.
This is RouteComponent and it's view:

```
import { Component } from '../Vendor/@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '../Vendor/@angular/router-deprecated';

import { LogInComponent } from './LogIn';

@Component({
    selector: 'reg',
    templateUrl: './Views/RegView.html',
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, LogInComponent],
    // styleUrls: ['../../Styles/bootstrap/bootstrap.css']
})

@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/logIn',
        name: 'LogIn',
        component: LogInComponent
    }
])

export class RegistrationComponent {

}
```

view:

```
> <from>
>     <div class=".col-lg-">
>         <div>
>             <input name="userName" placeholder="логин">
>         </div>
>         <div>
>             <input name="password1" placeholder="******">
>         </div>
>         <div>
>             <input name="password2" placeholder="******">
>         </div>
>         <div>
>             <button>Зарегестрироваться</button>
>         </div>
>         <div>
>             <button [routerLink]="['LogIn']">Вход</button>
>         </div>
>     </div> </from>
```

And this is LogInComponent, to whick RegistrationComponent should route:

```
import { Component } from '../Vendor/@angular/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '../Vendor/@angular/router-deprecated';

import { RegistrationComponent } from './Registration'

@Component({
    selector: 'logIn',
    templateUrl: './Views/LogInView.html',
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RegistrationComponent]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/registration',
        name: 'registration',
        component: RegistrationComponent
    }
])

export class LogInComponent {
    constructor() { console.log("1");}
}
```

view:

```
<from>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input name="userName" placeholder="логин">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input name="password1" placeholder="******">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button>Войти</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button [routerLink]="['Registration']">Регистрация</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</from>
```

And this is main ApplicationComponent. It should invoke(I hope that term is right) RegistrationComponent:

```
import { Component } from '../Vendor/@angular/core';

import { RegistrationComponent } from './Registration';


@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './Views/appview.html',
    directives: [ RegistrationComponent ]
})


export class AppComponent {

}
view:
<reg></reg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted `providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]` everywhere except boot. I don't know the reason why It helped, but everything is working now.

Comment: Because `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` should only be provided once at the root, otherwise each component gets another router instance.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , thank u again. You helped me a lot.